# IgnoreAccessChecksToAttribute does not grant access to internal types in referenced project

Tags: c#, .net

In my net5 project I have `.cs` file with `IgnoresAccessChecksToAttribute`

```cs
[assembly: IgnoresAccessChecksTo("MyOtherProject")]

namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public sealed class IgnoresAccessChecksToAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public IgnoresAccessChecksToAttribute(string assemblyName)
        {
            AssemblyName = assemblyName;
        }

        public string AssemblyName { get; }
    }
}
```

Also in my solution there is "MyOtherProject", which has some internal types. It is referenced via ProjectReference:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\MyOtherProject\MyOtherProject.csproj" />
```

When I try to use one of these internal types I am getting error

```
'Type' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `IgnoresAccessChecksToAttribute` is supported by the runtime, but not by the compiler. It is mainly intended to be used by dynamically generated code where no compiler support is needed.
There was a pull request to get it in the compiler but the Roslyn team rejected it, see https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/20870.

One possible way to do this is with the https://www.nuget.org/packages/IgnoresAccessChecksToGenerator package. That package will create reference assemblies for you so that the compiler is happy.

But since you want to use internal types from your own project, why don't you go the supported way of the [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute)? The `IgnoresAccessChecksToAttribute` is only needed if you can't change the code of the assembly containing the internal type.